# TestSuite creation for appium test

Tags: android, appium, test-suite

I am using appium for android hybrid app automation. I have created AppiumTest project inside my application project in android studio. I have created 4 test cases. I am using xml file to create test suite but on execution xml is ignored and all test case are executed.

`<suite name="Group" verbose="1"
    thread-count="10">
    <test name="skybet" thread-count="10">
        <classes>
            <class name="appiumtest.AndroidAppiumTest" />
            <class name="appiumtest.ExternalLinksCheck" />
            <class name="appiumtest.NetworkCheck" />
            <class name="appiumtest.SSOCheck" />
            </classes>
    </test>
</suite>`

How can I create test suite for these test cases?

Answer (score 0):

Just create separate test for each test case:

```
<suite name="Group" verbose="1"

thread-count="10">
<test name="skybet" thread-count="10">
    <classes>
        <class name="appiumtest.AndroidAppiumTest" />
        </classes>
</test>
<test name="skybet1" thread-count="10">

    <classes>
        <class name="appiumtest. ExternalLinksCheck" />
        </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Comment: I am using android studio as IDE and on running xml file. It doesn't execute any test case and shows result as pass. Do I need to include xml file in project configuration?

Comment: i edited my xml above. If this doesn't work try to put each test in different xml file and run it. Should work

Answer (score 0):

Xml file didn't work. I have used Test runner and able to create test suite. Here is the code: 
    package appiumtest;

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    LoginCheck.class,
    ExternalLinksCheck.class
    Video.class
})

public class MainTest {
}
```

Comment: I was executing my package instead of xml.